# How to configure preseed file to make grub configuration point to correct drive

Tags: boot, grub2, preseed

When I install debian using the preseeded file, I have a live USB stick mounted as `sda1` and ssd drive as `sdb1`. So I install MBR to `sdb1`. But when USB stick is removed SSD drive becomes `sda1`. And `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` does not work any more. I added a late command in order to fix that according to the documentation. It is simple and works if I run it manually on machine but fails in preseed (after restart the grub config file still has paths to `sdb1`).

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target sed -i 's/root\=\/dev\/sdb1/root\=\/dev\/sda1/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg; \
in-target update-grub;
```

So what is wrong here from the perspective of preseed?

PS:
I've also tried to forcefully generate grub config and run configuration within in target shell but that fails also:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg ; \
sed -i 's/root\=\/dev\/sdb1/root\=\/dev\/sda1/g' /target/boot/grub/grub.cfg; \
in-target bash -c 'update-grub';
```

Comment: Mounting /dev/sda1 in initramfs and checking the files shows that all those files were not updated. I tried also editing /etc/default/grub with `in-target sed -i 's#^\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet\)"$#\1 root=/dev/sda1"#' /etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually not to use the last update-grub, as it restores configuration to the one that is currently in use during installation.

So my preseed step is:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target sed -i 's#^\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet\)"$#\1 root=/dev/sda1"#' /etc/default/grub \
in-target grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg ; \
in-target sed -i 's/root\=\/dev\/sdb1/root\=\/dev\/sda1/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg ;
```